# Proof that a $3 \times 3$ matrix such that $A^2 = -I$ doesn’t exist

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $3 \times 3$ matrix such that $A^2 = -I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. Prove that such matrix $A$ can’t exist.

Comment: Have you tried applying some tools ? I guess the matrix has real entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If entries are real, consider the determinant of $A^2$, $\det(A^2) = \det(A) \cdot \det(A)$, it should be positive or zero, but $\det(-I) = -1$.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.